# apply calculation in pandas column with groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

what could be wrong in below code ?? 
a)I need a group by Area columns and apply some mathematical formula across columns:
b)Also if I have another column lets say the date and need to be added to groupby how will it come in below command

df3 = dataset.groupby('AREA')(['col1']+['col2']).sum()

table is in image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNH9i.png)

Comment: Please show us the original (raw) dataframe, and the result of dataframe you would expect from the groupby functions, thank you

Comment: It is always better if you could avoid images and paste the original data as text. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can sum column before grouping for better performance:

```
dataset['new'] = dataset['col1']+dataset['col2']
df3 = dataset.groupby('AREA', as_index=False)['new'].sum()
```

But your solution is possible in lambda function:

```
df3 = (dataset.groupby('AREA')
              .apply(lambda x: (x['col1']+x['col2']).sum())
              .reset_index(name='SUM'))
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000

dataset = pd.DataFrame({'AREA': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                        'col1': np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                        'col2':np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
#print (dataset)

In [24]: %%timeit
    ...: dataset['new'] = dataset['col1']+dataset['col2']
    ...: df3 = dataset.groupby('AREA', as_index=False)['new'].sum()
    ...: 
7.64 ms ± 50.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [25]: %%timeit
    ...: df3 = (dataset.groupby('AREA')
    ...:               .apply(lambda x: (x['col1']+x['col2']).sum())
    ...:               .reset_index(name='SUM'))
    ...:               
368 ms ± 5.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: what if I want to have 'area' also as a column in df3, what exactly does index falsing do ?

Comment: @user12853430 - answer was edited, previous wrongly removed `AREA` column.